# Which items will balance each other out in SMM2?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

In Super Mario Maker 2, Nintendo has added the seesaw item, which will tilt in either direction based on the weight of the items on it. Is there a master list of how much each item weighs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my own extensive experimenting, these were the results I came up with. The weights below are proportional to Mario.

## 0 Marios

These items can be pushed by the seesaw, but cannot weigh it down.

- Thwomp
- Twister

## 0.5 Marios

- Buzzy Shell
- Spiny Shell
- Dry Shell

## 0.75 Marios

- Super Mushroom
- 1-up Mushroom

## 1 Mario

- Coin dropped by a POW blast
- Fire Flower
- Superball Flower
- Empty Goomba Shoe
- Goomba
- Koopa Troopa
- Buzzy Beetle
- Spike Top
- Blooper
- Spiny
- Piranha Plant
- Monty Mole
- Rocky Wrench
- Hammer Bro
- Unchained Chomp
- Chain Chomp pole
- Boo
- Bob-omb
- Dry Bones
- Magikoopa
- P-switch
- POW Block
- Trampoline
- Rotten Mushroom
- Green Yoshi

## 1.25 Marios

- Big Mushroom

## 1.75 Marios

- Red Yoshi

## 2 Marios

- Muncher
- Chained Chomp
- Goomba Shoe with the Goomba
- Wiggler
- Bowser
- Bowser Jr.
- Boom Boom
- Bill Blaster (any height)
- Cannon

## 3 Marios

- 10-coin dropped by a POW blast

## Notes

- The big variant of all items doubles that item's weight. All other transformations do not affect the weight of the item, with the exception of the shells listed as 0.5 Marios and the two Yoshi variants.
- SM3DW-exclusive items do not appear on this list, as seesaws are unavailable in the SM3DW theme.
- Weights are stackable and transitive; two items each weighing 1 Mario will balance out one item weighing 2 Marios. Goomba shoes, for instance, weigh 1 Mario on their own and contain a Goomba weighing 1 Mario; they will exactly balance out a Muncher.
- Objects which bounce, such as Unchained Chomps, *do* have weights; they just won't balance the seesaw unless they remain on the ground, such as a Chained Chomp immediately before it attacks, or unless they are stacked on an enemy which remains on the ground. However, all bouncing items will cause the seesaw to wobble when they hit the seesaw.

  - The Super Star and Koopa Clown Car will therefore cause the seesaw to wobble, but as I'm unaware of a way for them to remain stationary on the ground, I can't measure their weights.
- Objects which do not interact with the ground, such as Super Leaves and Propeller Mushrooms, can neither push nor be pushed by the seesaw.
- Mario's powerup has no impact on his weight; small, big, and mega Mario all weigh the same.

---

All of the above is true *provided that all items are an equal distance from the fulcrum of the seesaw.* Seesaws in this game actually obey the physics of torque.

Torque is defined as force times the distance the object is from the fulcrum (τ=f*d). SMM2 actually implemented this, just like an IRL seesaw, with some rounding on the distance. So, for example, a fire flower placed at six blocks from the fulcrum will exactly balance out a Muncher placed at three blocks from the fulcrum. If the larger distance is odd, the smaller distance is rounded up; a fire flower at five blocks from the fulcrum will also balance out a Muncher at three blocks.

Comment: That’s weird, I’d think that Thwomps should be able to pull the seesaws down.

Comment: That's great to know. Thank you for the valuable self-answered content!

Comment: @Stormblessed I stacked Thwomps all the way to the top of the screen against a Buzzy shell and the Thwomps were still pushed up. I think they implemented them that way because of the whole catapult mechanic, particularly since Thwomps are traditionally stationary until triggered, but it does seem a bit odd.

Comment: @DonieIF Not surprising. Thwomps are kinda always levitating. Gravity doesnt seem to affect them and no gravity means no weight. Not having the game yet, it would be interesting to check if Thwomps move slower in Night low gravity levels.